Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 - Eclipse
i have a server tomcat that run correctly a project in eclipse but when i tried to run in debug it throws this error :
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jdt/launching/internal/javaagent/Premain : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:300)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:397)
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
Exception in thread "main" 

I know that should be a versioning error, the class is compiled in 1.8 and my project run in 1.7. I cannot understand this, why is working when i start the project, but for debug no ?
i attached here the config which contains the version used, if you wanna see more config please let me know. Thanks.





"The class is compiled in 1.8 and my project run in 1.7" - that's the problem already. Even if you limit the source to just use Java 7 functionality when the compiler generates Java 8 byte code only versions 8+ can execute it.

But how it is possible that if i start the server it works correctly but for debug no? How can i compile that class in java 1.7? from the error is possible to catch which classes is giving this error ?

This is the first class encountered by the JVM compiler for Java 8. I strongly suggest you migrate to Java 8.

Even if this should be the solution, i cannot move my project in Java 8.

@user85421 i added the picture for the server configuration, it still run in 1.7

I see, maybe the problem is with Eclipse itself, looks like the wrong class is org/eclipse/jdt/launching/internal/javaagent/Premain

Can you please explain more in depth what you mean? is a problem of a javaagent? How can i solve?

What Java version are you running Eclipse with? The issue seems to be that the Premain has been compiled for Java 8 and when you're debugging Eclipse it "injects" that class. So you might have to either upgrade your project to Java 8 or newer (the newest LTS version would be ideal to be set for the future) or downgrade Eclipse to a version that uses Java 7 or below.

It looks like your version of Eclipse does not support debugging programs using a JRE earlier than v1.8.0.  It is running your program with the v1.7 JRE you specify in the project settings, but trying to insert debug tooling in the form of its own class org.eclipse.jdt.launching.internal.javaagent.Premain, which is built for Java 1.8.
Your best move would probably be to bite the bullet, and move up to an LTS Java version that is still supported (by Oracle, let alone Eclipse).  That would be at least Java 8 / 1.8, but if you undertake the exercise at all then you would be wise to jump to the latest LTS version (8, 11, 17, or 21) you can reasonably handle.
But you can probably kick that can a little farther down the road by running the software against at least a Java 8 JRE, even though you build it against Java 7.  Among the settings depicted in the question, look at the one showing the "JRE" tab.  You would want to install the chosen Java 8+ runtime on your system, and on that tab, configure it as the runtime JRE.  The runtime JRE does not have to exactly match the Java version for which the software was built.
